Функция wait() требует слишком быстрого нажатия (Python)
Решил сделать приложение которое будет помогать людям изучать формы времени в английском языке. Ход работы приложения прост: при помощи библиотеки turtle пишем текст, ждем пока пользователь прочитает и нажмет пробел, Черепашка стирает старый текст и пишет новый. Но если не нажимать пробел в течение пяти секунд то программа намертво зависает, есть ли возможность предотовратить это или какие-нибудь аналоги для wait()?
read_key и msvcrt.getch() уже пробовал, результат тот же
import turtle,keyboard

def wcw (text):
    keyboard.wait(' ')
    turtle.clear()
    turtle.write(text,font=30)

turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.penup()
turtle.right(180)
turtle.fd(200)

turtle.write("В английском языке есть разные формы времени",font=30)
wcw("Зная их можно перевести на английский предложение:\nЯ чищу зубы каждый день")
wcw("Сейчас я расскажу о форме времени - present simple")
turtle.exitonclick()


Но если нажать не нажимать - так нажать или не нажимать? уточните, пожалуйста, нажав [edit]

По поводу getch - он только в консоли работает, а не в оконных приложениях.

aleksandr barakin, исправил

вы бы для начала с русскими деепричастными оборотами разобрались.

Пробуйте использовать средства "черепашки" для ввода вместо модуля keyboard: https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.onkey. В целом, если вам какой-то текстовый опросник нужен, не понятно зачем вообще тут черепашка, возьмите tkinter, например (поверх которого черепашка работает). Почему с wait зависает - потому что вы цикл обработки событий блокируете. Нужно вместо этого на событие нажатия кнопки реагировать.
